# How do I refocus on an input field after tabbing past the last one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have thee input fields. Two require input one is type submit. Like you see below.

```
<input id="cs1"   type="text"   value="" placeholder="Call Sign"  onkeyup="showHint(this.value);"  maxlength="16" onmousedown="isKeyPressed(event)" autofocus="autofocus" />

<input id="Fname" type="text"   value="" name="Fname" placeholder="First Name" onkeyup="nameHint(this.value);" onblur="checkIn();" />

<input id="ckin1" type="submit" value="Check In"  />
```

The usual method is input into cs1, which drops hints at possible values. Select a possible value and tab to the Name input. At which time a name may have been automatically filled or not. Either enter the name or accept the one there. Then tab to the submit input and either click on it or press tab.
This is where the problem is, if you tab you are placed on the URL (address bar) which is bad. If you click the submit the cursor is returned correctly to the cs1 input again.
I've tried all kinds of stuff like you see below, but none of it works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ckin1').on('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            document.body.firstElementChild.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;

        }
    });
})
$(document).ready(function () {
$( "#ckin1" ).click(function() {
                $( "#cs1" ).focus();
            });
       });
```

How do I get the cursor to return automatically to the cs1 input filed after a tab from the ckin1 submit?

Comment: Instead of `keydown` try `keyup`... try that once!

Comment: `$('a').on( 'keyup', function( e ) {
    if( e.which == 9 ) {
        console.log( 'Here' );
    }
} );`

Comment: Changing to 'keyup' didn't appear to change the behavior. The cursor still lands on the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine. Since you are already using jQuery, use it to focus the first element.

```js
$("#ckin1").on('keydown', function(e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

  if (keyCode == 9 && !e.shiftKey) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#cs1').focus();
    return false;
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cs1"   type="text"   value="" placeholder="Call Sign"  maxlength="16" />

<input id="Fname" type="text"   value="" name="Fname" placeholder="First Name" />

<input id="ckin1" type="submit" value="Check In"  />
```

Comment: I'm afraid this change still made no difference in behavior. Starting on the first (cs1) input tag, two tabs still puts the cursor on the URL.

Comment: @KeithDKaiser Then you will need to post more code, reproducing the problem. If you run that snippet it works correctly.

Comment: #gforce301 happy to do that but the code is quite extensive I'm not sure how much more to include. Can you give me some guidelines?

Comment: @KeithDKaiser Try to provide an example of it **not** working. I understand your use case is complicated (most usually are). The problem is that if you push the "Run code snippet" button on my answer, it works. So in order to help you I need to see it broken so I can help you fix it.  Reading [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), migth help.

Comment: OK I'll try and find a way to simplify in such a way I can show how it DOESN'T work. Hard to do... since its already broken. I think your code should be fixing the issue but my surrounding code is so much more complex (at least in my mind) that I don't know how to fix it. Would you be interested in seeing the application as its currently running?

Comment: @KeithDKaiser Certainly. If there is a way you could show it to me, I would be glad to help.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to send you my email. You send me yours and I'll send you the URL. Or we can setup a chat... but I don't know how.